# How to do timestamp conversion where the time zone value comes from another column

Tags: sql, presto, timestamp-with-timezone

Is there a clever way to use convert a timestamp to another time zone when the other timezone value is in a different column?

eg. `Select cast('2018-11-16 21:31:40.000 America/Los_Angeles') as timestamp with time zone) At time zone 'UTC'` --> this works fine

BUT what if the `UTC` value had to come from a different column. So, something like this:

```
`cast('2018-11-16 21:31:40.000 America/Los_Angeles') as timestamp with time zone) At time zone newTZ `
```

--> where newTZ is a column name in the same table

(The flavor of SQL I am using is Presto but let's ignore that for a min)

Comment: why do you want to do so thought? timezones are usually used for the view part and can be manipulated before displaying to the user. same goes vice versa - get from the user the time in their timezone and look at the db with UTC timezone. that will increase performance and make the queries more readable. does this make any sense for your use case?

Comment: @BenYitzhaki I am doing something very similar..my roadblock is how do i convert timezone after I grab the timezone value from a user table.
What I am doing: Basically, I have a bunch of records that are handled by agents. Each record has `created_time` in UTC but agents are located in different timezones, meaning Monday in UTC may still be Sunday in Pacific. What I am trying to do is provide SLA times based on business hours. In summary, I need the day of the week in agent timezones for some calculations.

Comment: i'm not familiar with presto, but in case its supported, in mysql i have done something similar using a `convert_tz` method https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz it supports the values as parameters as you need

Comment: I believe presto does support some mysql functions out of box. I will give it a try and post what I get! Thank you!

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen That worked! I don't understand why `at_timezone` function isn't mentioned anywhere in the docs. And yes, my question was exact duplicate of that. Thank you for your help finding the solution!

Comment: The function is hidden. There is an issue about it